# Have any Marvel/DC superheroes died of natural causes?

Tags: marvel, dc, comics, super-hero

Reviewing an answer on another question, someone posited that Professor X is a mutant, and thus not subject to normal rules of mortality. This isn't really true, but it brought up an interesting idea, and after wracking my brain, I can't come up with a single example.

**Within the Marvel or DC universes, has any superhero died of *natural* causes (old age, natural disease, etc)?**

For purposes of this question, let's limit this to primary continuities/universes (The Watchmen was published by DC, but don't exist within the main DC universe). Being killed in a battle, or from injuries sustained in a battle would also not count.

Comment: Is poor comic book circulation a natural cause?

Comment: Just to point out, it's very natural to die when you are repeatedly shot, stabbed, electrocuted, and dropped in acid.  It is, in fact, quite ***unnatural*** to survive those.  Thus, you could argue that Uncle Ben died of natural causes!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are several super-powered characters from both DC and Marvel on Wikipedia's [List of deceased American comic book characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_deceased_American_comic_book_characters) who died of mundane causes. (Credit to [Sean Duggan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/58408/63) for finding that list.)

#### DC Universe

- [Amazing-Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazing-Man_%28DC_Comics%29#Will_Everett) died of cancer.
- [Black Canary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Canary) died of cancer. (This was after exposure to radiation during a battle, so it's not really a natural death. It was also retconned a few years later.)
- [Enemy Ace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enemy_Ace) died of natural causes.
- [The Question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_%28comics%29) died of lung cancer.

#### Marvel

- [Captain Marvel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Marvel_%28Mar-Vell%29) (Mar-Vell) died of cancer from toxic nerve gases (so not really a natural death).
- [Dennis Sykes](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Dennis_Sykes_(Earth-616)) died of cancer (as a direct result of the chemicals that gave him superpowers, but he had one month to live).
- [Jeffrey Mace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffrey_Mace) (the Patriot, and once Captain America) died of cancer.
- [Trick Shot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trick_Shot_%28comics%29) died of cancer.
- [Two-Gun Kid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-Gun_Kid) died of natural causes.
- [Union Jack (Brian Falsworth)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_Jack_%28comics%29#Brian_Falsworth) died in an automobile accident.
- [Union Jack (James Montgomery Falsworth)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_Jack_%28comics%29#James_Montgomery_Falsworth) died of heart attack.
- [Whizzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whizzer_%28comics%29) died of a heart attack (but this was during a battle, so not really a natural death).

Comment: You did a much more comprehensive job than I did. Since my answer really doesn't add anything to yours, I'm going to delete it tonight, I think.

Comment: Apparently cancer is most every heroes secret weakness...

Comment: Also, Marvel apparently hates British super heroes.

Comment: Captain Marvel's death is the most memorable one to me. I need to read that again.

Comment: @Doc - Even Wolverine's!  It turns out he's like, 90% cancer and is only alive because of his healing factor.